# How to remove "Edit" Link for Leads ListView in Sugarcrm for the records having status = 'Converted'?

Tags: php, edit, crm, sugarcrm, vtiger

How to remove "Edit" Link for Leads ListView in "SugarCRM Community Edition 6.5.16" for the records having status = 'Converted'.

Regards,
Vishal Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this in a while, but here's how I'd approach it.

That quick edit link comes from `/include/ListView/ListViewData.php`, in ListViewData::getAdditionalDetails. Search for the bits that show the "edit_inline.png" image.

From there we can see that showing the Edit button is derived from the Roles-driven privilege to edit the record **and** the result of an ambiguous method $adFunction. That ambiguous method comes from a module-specific file additionalDetails.php that is part of the module's metadata.

If we look into the Accounts module for an example, you can see how `/modules/Accounts/metadata/additionalDetails.php` has a function `additionalDetailsAccount` that returns an array with an `editLink` key. Remove this key, and you remove the edit button.

To make it upgrade safe, don't modify `/modules/Accounts/metadata/additionalDetails.php` directly, but instead create `custom/modules/Accounts/metadata/additionalDetails.php` and copy the original contents to it, removing the `editLink` key.

Repair & Rebuild, and good luck.

Comment: This is not the thing i m looking for. I want to make it through coding.

Comment: I think we have a language barrier. I told you how to do it with code. I just haven't written the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actally he want to do it conditionally, like in subpanel 5 rows, i think he want's to show those rows which have some flag true. 
like only show edit buttons with those rows who's show flag is true.

Comment: How this answer help in fixing issue to OP?

Comment: In Sugar 7.x add file subpanels.php in following directory
custom/modules/<module>/clients/base/layouts/subpanels/subpanels.php
Copy all code from module directory and paste into this file.
in subpanel you want to edit add  this line
'override_subpanel_list_view'=>'custom_opportunity_subpanel_list',
and add view file in following directoty
custom/module/<subpanel_module>/clients/base/views/custom_opportunity_subpanel_list.php
custom/module/<subpanel_module>/clients/base/views/custom_opportunity_subpanel_list.js
In js file "extendsFrom: 'SubpanelListView', "
and after render function your logic